# Подключение базы данных в Docker.(psycopg2.OperationalError) could not translate host name "postgres" to address: Temporary failure in name resolution

Tags: python, postgresql, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

Не получается подключить БД к приложению в docker-compose.

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.11

RUN mkdir /fastapi_app

WORKDIR /fastapi_app

COPY requirements.txt .

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . .
```

Docker-compose

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  db:
    container_name: postgres
    image: postgres:alpine3.18
    restart: always
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    networks:
      - custom
    env_file:
      - backend/.env
  app:
    build:
      context: /backend
    env_file:
      - backend/.env
    container_name: fastapi_app
    command: ["/fastapi_app/docker/app.sh"]
    ports:
      - 9999:8000
    depends_on:
      - db    
networks:
  custom:
    driver: bridge
```

app.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

alembic upgrade head

cd backend

gunicorn main:app --workers 4 --worker-class uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker --bind=0.0.0.0:8000
```

.env

```
DB_HOST=postgres
DB_PORT=5432
DB_NAME=postgres
DB_USER=postgres
DB_PASS=postgres
```

Приложение запускается, БД запускается, но нет подключения к БД, ошибка:

```
 sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) could not translate host name "postgres" to address: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

Comment: Ты забыл ` networks:
      - custom` в секции `app:`.